# Update killed email

Tags: email

After install Ubuntu 18.04 everything worked OK for a while but some (unknown) update later killed incoming POP3 email, although outgoing is OK. ISP settings are correct and email works on all of my non-Ubuntu devices. Delete account and configure IMAP is no help.

Reformat drive, reinstall Ubuntu 16-something, email OK. Upgrade to 18.04, email still OK. But after various updates, POP3 stopped working.

Email is Thunderbird (60.6.1), but another email app exhibits same problem.

Anyone experience this?

Comment: [Please enable logging](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Linux.2Funix) and provide the log. Redact passwords. And provide any error messages you get.

Comment: We'll need logs from both applications to know what exactly is going on.  There's not enough info to debug this.